# Corporate proxy block all traffic except HTTP through a proxy server. How to use GEM or SVN, etc in Windows?

Tags: proxy

Our development team has spent countless hours setting up our individual Windows PCs to work with the corporate network. We work in a large company with tons of bureaucracy involved, which includes network access.

Youtube, Twitter, Facebook, and many programming/forums websites are blocked due to faulty filtering settings, so are many other useful sites for coding.

To get this policy fixed will take months. We are trying to use Ruby Gems, SVN, and GIT, and many other command line tools that won't work due to network restrictions.

Question: Is there a way to socksify the entire Windows environment, so we don't have to individually set the proxy for each individual app?

Our environment is Windows XP.

Thanks,
-John
San Jose, California

Answer (score 0):

Most applications on Windows that use sockets, go through the standard WinInet stack. Setting a proper proxy for Internet Explorer actually sets it for the whole WinInet stack as well, so it should work for other apps as well.

Note however, that you need to explicitly open the Advanced dialog for the proxy settings in IE and uncheck the `Use same proxy for all protocols` checkbox to be able to enables SOCKS support. Otherwise, the proxy settings only affect couple of protocols, so you would still need to configure your tools to use `http:` instead of tool-specific protocols like `svn:`.

Comment: I would have to disagree. Actually, I find it's only a small minority of apps that actually use WinInet and thus make use of the settings configured in Internet Explorer. This is of course dependent on what applications a user has installed on a given machine, but from what I observe in day-to-day business nowadays, I rarely find this to be true anymore.

Comment: @Jim Brissom - so what do apps use nowadays? Do they actually come with their own sockets stack?

Comment: I'm sure you would agree that using WinInet is different from employing the socket stack in windows - I can very well call WSASocket, send a HTTP request and happily ignore whatever the user configured in Internet Explorer. Quite a different story than the likes of InternetOpenUrl,HttpOpenRequest etc. wouldn't you say?

Comment: Umh, yes, you are correct. :-) I would still not expect many applications to actually call directly WSASocket, but I might be wrong of course. Of course, any application that does this directly has to be configured manually through app-specific settings what proxy to use.

Answer (score 0):

If one of you can share his or her net access from home and can operate a PC there as a "server", then you can set up a HTTP tunnel using SSH. See details here: http://www.buzzsurf.com/surfatwork/ or google "how to bypass firewalls at work".